# Change Window List back color

Tags: gnome, themes

[image]

I can't change the "Windows List" background color to black (the same background color of my main panel, in gnome)... and the final effect is quite bad!
Can anyone know where to change this parameter ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by the theme, and different engines have different results.

It most likely is the case that your chosen theme uses a pixmap at as the panel background, thus resulting in poor results when resized.

You can:

- Try another theme, quite likely that should fix it.
- Try editing the theme's gtkrc to see if you can remove the references to a panel.rc (if it has one) or modify the panel appearance.

Answer (score 0):

It is  recommended installing the GNOME Tweaks application, formerly known as GNOME Tweak Tool, to change your theme.

To install it graphically, open the Ubuntu Software application, search for “tweaks,” and then install the GNOME Tweaks application.

To install GNOME Tweaks from a terminal window, run the following command instead:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

From there, you can improve the existing settings or use a better theme

source: https://www.howtogeek.com/358049/how-to-install-desktop-themes-on-ubuntu-18.04-lts/